# Populating fragment fields from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a ViewPager of 3 fragments. All 3 fragments are of the same type, with identical layouts, but they are to hold different (text) information. I am trying to create my activity, where I create the fragments and prepare the text data that I will populate my fragments with. However, I can't seem to work with the fragments from within my activity. All the activity's lifecycle methods are executed before the fragment lifecycle methods. So if I try to update a textview in a fragment from within my activity, it won't work, because the textview is null in the fragment.

I'm going to need to make periodic updates to the fragments, so passing the data as a bundle is not an option. Plus, since I'm passing lots of text, I'm using a StringBuilder object, which is not something I can pass in a bundle (unless I make it Parcelable, which I don't want)

I think I could run a method from within my fragment class that would execute during fragment creation, but that means all 3 fragments would run this method. That's not really the level of control I'm looking for.

Is there a neat way to make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep references to your fragments, and let them all implement an interface with a common update-method. As an example, let's make it super clear and call the interface `Updatable` with one method called 'update':

```
public interface Updatable {
    public void update(String text);
}
```

Now, in your Activity's onCreate, save references to your Updatables there (i.e. when you lookup or instantiate your Fragments).
It should now be trivial to update your Fragments when necessary from the Activity. Needless to say, the fragment implementation of the update code needs to do the actual update of the TextView(s).

If the update implementation is exactly the same for all your Fragments, your could save some lines of code and make a base class which implements Updatable and extends Fragment.

Comment: The first necessary step is to update the fragments when Activity is created or at least resumed. None of the fragments' fields are initialized by that point though.

Comment: I ended up using interfaces after restructuring some of my logic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you might able to populating fragment fields during `onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.

Refer to this site for more information about fragments' life cycle:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Observer pattern... there is a really great implementation which you can include as gradle dependency called EventBus:
https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: I followed the instructions, but the fragments are registering after the first event is posted (which I do in onResume of my activity)

Comment: you should use postSticky instead of post - that way fragment will receive sticky event as soon as you register it to eventbus

Answer (score 0):

You can use Otto Bus to send data to your fragments from your activity.
http://square.github.io/otto/

Create a new bus in you application class

```
Bus bus = new Bus();
```

Create an event that contains your data which you'll pass to fragments.

```
bus.post(new MyDataEvent(data));
```

Register your fragment in your fragment's onResume() (Do not forget to unregister in your fragment's onPause())

```
bus.register(this);
```

And get data with subscribe in your fragment

```
@Subscribe 
public void onDataReceived(MyDataEvent event) {
    // TODO Do what ever you want
}
```

I hope this'll help you.